# Burn-in period for random walk

Tags: time-series, simulation

We are trying to make simulation experiment involving a common stochastic trend, that is described by the random walk (or $I(1)$ process) $Y_t = Y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$, where innovations $\varepsilon_t$ ~ $N(0,1)$. However when could we be sure that the past innovations are more or less reasonably included into the stochastic trend?  Is there any good proxy for random-walk's burn-in period?

I've looked for R's burn-in default suggestion for $AR(p)$ part: `ceiling(6/log(minroots))`, meaning that in case of unit root we get infinity here and roughly tried to take close to unity root 1.0001 (actually it is the same like taking 60000 at once). So any reasonable suggestions or rule of thumbs you do use in practice?

Comment: Could you add a bit more context please? e.g. what R function and package are you using?

Comment: A link explaining why random-walk needs a burn-in also would help.

Comment: Well we will use diffinv() directly, but the burn-in default could be found in arima.sim() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burn-in doesn’t make sense here.  The random walk you describe does not have a stationary distribution.

Comment: Well, I do know that the process is not stationary. Burn-in period's purpose is to be more or less confident that the starting history values are already present in the stochastic trend, in the sense that we may assume that we have started from the long long past. It is not clear why I have to go from zero if I don't want to. And else it would be interesting to hear some suggestions about the same questions when the process is random walk with drift component.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to simulate a stochastic trend. Why not initialize $Y_0$ to a random value, say a sample from $N(0,\sigma^2)$ with $\sigma^2$ large?

Comment: One more comment.  The problem with burn-in is that, in addition to being non-stationary, the process is not ergodic.  So what you are asking for is not really possible.  You will always be able to infer (roughly) what the initial value of the process is.

Comment: So if I understand well building up some common stochastic trend (to have cointegrating relationship) do not affect the Monte Carlo simulation results whatever the starting value will be? On the other hand it is the ergodicity property that insures the "memory" length, that after some period of development you can not tell what the starting value was.Again in Gaussian random walk case how could you infer (roughly)the initial value if you drop sufficiently large burn-in part, if you don't or do know the length of burn-in (say T) the confidence interval of +/- 2$\sqrt{T}$ is too rough isn't it?

Comment: Suppose $Y_t = \alpha Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ where $\epsilon_t$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ and $|\alpha| \leq 1$.  The conditional distribution of $Y_t$ given $Y_0$ is $N(\alpha^t Y_0, \sigma_{\alpha,t}^2)$, where $\sigma_{\alpha,t}^2 \leq t$ depends only on $\alpha$ and $t$.  If $\alpha = 1$, note that $Y_t$ given $Y_0$ remains centered at $Y_0$ even as $t \to \infty$.  In that sense, you can always infer $Y_0$.  On the other hand, if $|\alpha|< 1$ then the conditional mean of $Y_t$ given $Y_0$ tends to 0 as $t\to\infty$ so that asymptotically $Y_t$ is conditionally independent of $Y_0$.

Comment: If $|\alpha| = 1$, then $\sigma_{\alpha,t}^2 = t$. If $|\alpha| < 1$, then  $\sigma_{\alpha,t}^2 = (1-\alpha^t) / (1-\alpha)$.  So although you can infer $Y_0$ from $Y_t$ when $\alpha = 1$ the standard error will be of the order $\sqrt{t}$.  I think to better answer your question you need to be less specific and explain what you will use $Y_t$ for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and even though it is correct I'm still a bit confused. My point was since you do drop the burn-in period, you can't track back to the original point, but do continue from some point $Y_T$, pretending that there was some history to get you to the point. Therefore you can't say for sure what was the original $Y_0$ value you started from, and even more due to self-similarity it will be $Y_T$ the new point to build the mean value (again for a particular realization! not on average). Building the question I was just curious what usually people do for RW in Simulations.

Comment: I was not originally planning to give more details on the experiment we do perform, but it seems that we need more details on the DGP in simulation experiments. Suppose we try to simulate to factors $F_{i,t} = \alpha_i F_{i,t-1} + \beta_i G_{t} + \nu_{i,t}$, $i = 1,2,\dots,k$, where $\nu_{i,t}$ (and any other residuals) are i.i.d $N(0,1)$, where $G_t$ is a common stochastic trend. Then we build many "factor-based" series $x_{j,t} = \sum_i \lambda_{i,j}F_{i,t} + \varepsilon_{j,t}$, $j = 1,\dots,n$, where $\lambda_{i,j}$ are randomly drawn from $N(0,\sigma_j^2)$. The same factors are used for

Comment: the dependent variable $y_{t} = \sum_i \gamma_{i}F_{i,t} + \varepsilon_{t}$. The point is how to bring common stochastic trend into the model, and when we can say that the trend is nice. May be in this case it indeed doesn't matter if we start from "looking as in real data" trend or actually take any part of it... in any case we will standardize the auxiliary processes latter on, but would like to see at least by simulations if the problem we are working on (actually it is temporal disaggregation) could be done for non-stationary but co-integrated data. Thanks again for details you provided :)

Comment: @Dmitrij I don’t think I can help you further.  But generally, when performing simulations you want the model to be close to reality as possible.  I sometimes fit my model to some typical data and then simulate from the fitted model as if it were true.  When simulating from a stationary random walk, people often want to sample from its stationary distribution, but its stationary distribution is hard to sample from directly so that initializing $X_0$ to the stationary distribution is not possible.  In that case burn-in makes sense so that $X_t$ for some large $t$ is approx. stationary.